# Qt cannot find library

Tags: android, qt, rtl-sdr

I'm currently trying to make a simple app for Android using Qt. The app should comunicate with a rtlsdr dongle using the librtlsdr. I managed to compile this library for android obtaining the .so file.
But i got an error when i try to compile the program:

**/home/pedro/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: cannot find -librtlsdr.so**

I'm currently including the library using the following lines in the .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../librtlsdr-android/build/src
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../librtlsdr-android/build/include
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../librtlsdr-android/build/src/ -librtlsdr.so
```

I'm using Qt 5.13.2, compiling with qmake.

Comment: try `LIBS += -L$$PWD/../librtlsdr-android/build/src/ -librtlsdr`

Comment: I get exactly the same error message but with "cannot find -librtlsdr".
thanks for your reply.